# How to set up a computer network with ruby

Tags: ruby, networking

I would like to set up a network with some computers I have, where they can connect to one main source, then receive and send messages back to it. I have never done any network programming before, so I'm just wondering what are the best tutorials using Ruby that I could use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are about a billion ways you could do this.  Could you post more about what the problem is you're trying to solve, or what the content/purpose/size/format/etc. of the messages is to be?  Are you building something "for real" or just trying to learn network programming?

Also, do you already have the lower layer stuff figured out?  You have networking infrastructure setup, IP addresses assigned, etc?  If not, you'll need to get through that.  Once you have that, you could start with a [tutorial on basic socket programming in Ruby](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm), but - depending on the answers to the questions above - you might not want to "roll your own" solution at that level.  The answer might be to use an [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) (Jabber) server, and use an XMPP client library, or you might want to deploy something like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org), [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq), etc. and use a library for interfacing with that.  Or maybe you want to use HTTP and pass messages around in JSON, or XML or $WHATEVER.  In short, there are a LOT of options in this area.